# Implementing linkedin login in the live server

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have implemented linkedin login in my website. The user enters his username and password through my website form and after successful login, I retrieve the user information and display it to user in my webpage. This is working fine in the localhost wampserver.

But when I deployed it to the live server, it is not working correctly.
When I enter the email address and password of the linkedin. I am redirected to the linkedin page. This is the url:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorizedialog/submit
```

And this is the error I get.

```
Request Error
We’re sorry, there was a problem with your request. Please make sure you have cookies enabled and try again.

Or follow this link to return to the home page.
```

However, in localhost. I am redirected to this page. I get user information successfully. 
Why is it not working in the server. Here is my linkedin code:

```
<form action="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorizedialog/submit" method="POST" name="oauth2SAuthorizeForm" novalidate="novalidate" class="grant-access" data-jsenabled="check">




<input type="hidden" name="isJsEnabled" value="true">

<div class="login">
 <p class="description">Sign in to LinkedIn and allow access:</p>
 <ul>
 <li class="email-input">

 <label for="session_key-oauth2SAuthorizeForm" id="yui-gen1" style="display: none;">Email</label>



 <script id="controlinit-http-12157-7141289-1" type="text/javascript+initialized" class="li-control">

 /* extlib: _ghostlabel */



 LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12157-7141289-1', 'GhostLabel', {});
 </script>


 <div class="fieldgroup">
 <input type="text" name="session_key" value="" id="session_key-oauth2SAuthorizeForm" autocorrect="off" autocapitalization="off" data-ime-mode-disabled="" placeholder="Email">
 <span class="error" id="session_key-oauth2SAuthorizeForm-error"></span>
 </div>
 <a target="_blank" href="/reg/join">Join LinkedIn</a>
 </li>
 <li class="password-input">

 <label for="session_password-oauth2SAuthorizeForm" id="yui-gen2" style="display: none;">Password</label>





 <script id="controlinit-http-12157-7141289-2" type="text/javascript+initialized" class="li-control">


 LI.Controls.addControl('control-http-12157-7141289-2', 'GhostLabel', {});
 </script>


 <div class="fieldgroup">
 <input type="password" name="session_password" value="" id="session_password-oauth2SAuthorizeForm" autocorrect="off" autocapitalization="off" maxlength="250" placeholder="Password">
 <span class="error" id="session_password-oauth2SAuthorizeForm-error"></span>
 </div>

 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<ul class="duration">
</ul>

<div class="actions">
 <ul>
 <li>
 <input type="submit" name="authorize" value="Allow access" class="allow">
 </li>
 <li><a href="http://carwarehouseonline.com/test.php?error=access_denied&amp;error_description=the+user+denied+your+request&amp;state=STATE" class="cancel">Cancel</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="logo">LinkedIn</div>
</div>






 <input type="hidden" name="oauth_token" value="na" id="oauth_token-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="appId" value="" id="appId-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="1ba8ogpm9e05" id="client_id-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="scope" value="r_basicprofile r_emailaddress" id="scope-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="state" value="STATE" id="state-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://127.0.0.1:8088/linkedin/test.php" id="redirect_uri-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="scope_id" value="1001" id="scope_id-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="authorized" value="true" id="authorized-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:4651646934577528060" id="csrfToken-oauth2SAuthorizeForm"><input type="hidden" name="sourceAlias" value="0_9DsHd_bZgogqUxUum9_VlTBWJMUCeow0cdGxvyKqdV8" id="sourceAlias-oauth2SAuthorizeForm">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the error is happening with the callback. The user should be redirected back to your application.please check your request uri again

Comment: I have doubled checked it. The request uri is redirecting me properly in localhost but not in live server

Answer (score 0):

Its not capturing your session properly.Please have a close look with your session code.